# Interpretation of adiabatic assumption in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, definition, topological-phase

This thought just occurred to me. I recall from my quantum mechanics courses that adiabatic transformation is defined as a process in which a band-gap is kept open while the process is carried in a slow manner. My understanding is that we want the slowness of adiabatic transformation for:

1. we want to assume that at every point along the path of the transformation, we have a Hilbert space.
2. we want to keep the energetic hierarchy of the quantum states of interest (i.e. we do not mix them).

Are there any other interpretations of this adiabatic assumption?

---

Apparently, my interpretation is unrelated to the adiabatic assumption, as pointed out by TLDR in the comments. Adiabatic assumption means that during the transformation, our system stays in a specific state throughout.

Comment: Incidentally, points 1 and 2 are independent of the slowness of the transformation.  Separation of time scales is only necessary in order to avoid transitions between energy levels.  The adiabatic approximation has several consequences: (i) the 'lightest' quantum degrees of freedom can induce a potential energy landscape for the 'heaviest' ones, (ii) the dynamical behavior of a semi-classical system can change somewhat dramatically when the 'fast' degrees of freedom undergo transitions to new energy levels.

Comment: @TLDR Thanks for the comment! I see! What do you mean by 'lightest' and 'heaviest' quantum degrees of freedom?

Comment: you may notice that most quantum systems have inertial or tunneling components/operators, which are often defined through momenta of various sorts.  A 'heavy' degree of freedom can be viewed of as a coordinate whose inertia is (relatively) large, or whose tunneling rate is (relatively) small, allowing the associated component of the wave function to be (relatively) localized and exhibit semi-classical behavior.

Comment: @TLDR, I see. You mean operators with small transition matrix elements, when evolved, may result in operators whose matrix elements correspond to 'larger' transition amplitudes, right?

Comment: Not exactly... small transition matrix elements tend to allow wave functions to 'concentrate' near potential energy minima and/or classical dynamical paths of least action (as when the method of stationary phase is applied to the path integral.)

Comment: @TLDR, Thanks! When you say "the 'lightest' quantum degrees of freedom can induce a potential energy landscape for the 'heaviest' ones", do you mean there are emergent degrees of freedom that differs drastically from the original quantum degrees of freedom before the transformation?

Comment: Not necessarily.